# KSOAP2 android confused about namespaces / url and HttpTransportSE's call() function throws EOF-Exception

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I can't figure out why my soap request on Android does not work, I followed the tutorial on https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242

Which is basically my code as follows:

public class SoapClient {

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "https://ieslamp.technikum-wien.at/sys_bvu4_17_l/JamDec/ContentManager/soapservice.php";

//not used right now
private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://ieslamp.technikum-wien.at/soap/getJamRoutes";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://ieslamp.technikum-wien.at/sys_bvu4_17_l/JamDec/ContentManager/soapservice.php/getJamRoutes";
//which is the URL I need? some tutorials say it's the url to the wsdl, but others say it's the location of the webservice
private static final String POST_URL = "https://ieslamp.technikum-wien.at/sys_bvu4_17_l/JamDec/ContentManager/soapservice.php?wsdl";
private static final String LOCATION_URL = "https://ieslamp.technikum-wien.at:443/sys_bvu4_17_l/JamDec/ContentManager/soapservice.php";

private Context context;

public SoapClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public String getJamsFromServer() {


    String methodname = "getJamRoutes";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(TARGET_NAMESPACE, methodname);
    String routes = null;

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
    try {
        ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerPropertyArrayList);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
         routes = result.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return routes;
}


private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    return envelope;
}

private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY, LOCATION_URL, 1200000);
    ht.debug = true;

    ht.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
    return ht;
}

}
```

The service returns a "Hello World" - String, and I am using SOAP-UI to test it and a request with this software actually gives me a response, but when I am trying to make a response with my Android app -

```
ht.call();
```

throws a EOF-Exception on me and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Can you maybe explain which namespace and url for -

```
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

I actually need? And do I use the targetNamespace or Namespace? I can't figure out while researching.

Here is my generated wsdl file:

Thank you for your Help!

Comment: You can find my generated WSDL file at https://ieslamp.technikum-wien.at/sys_bvu4_17_l/JamDec/ContentManager/soapservice.php?wsdl

I could not put it into my question, because I had problems with formating :(

Also I forgot to mention I am using ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

as my soap library for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself, it seems that the newest jar file does not work. If you are going to use ksoap I would recommend you to use older versions which are flagged as deprecated, but they will at least do the job.

Comment: can you please share the jar link or jar you have